# My code isn't outputting my random mysql query. Help?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

the code is pretty self explanatory. I'm trying to use sql to retrieve a random a record, along with it's values. However, when I uploaded this, all I got from the source code was

```
<a href="/.php">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/" 
                   alt="" 
              />
            </div>
          </a>
```

Here's my code:

```
<?php
// Get the number of rows in the table
$count = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT COUNT(thumbnailID) FROM images'));
// Use those to generate a random number
$count = floatval($count);
$rand = rand(1,$count);
// Select the two columns we need, and use limit to set the boundaries
$query = 'SELECT link, pic, alt FROM images LIMIT '.$rand.',1';
// Run the query
if(($result = mysql_query($query)) !== FALSE) {
    // Dump the result into two variables
    list($link, $pic, $alt) = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
    // Echo out the result
          echo '
          <a href="/' . $link . '.php">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/' . $pic . '" 
                   alt="' . $alt . '" 
              />
            </div>
          </a>';
}
?>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure that table has any records in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this first

```
$count = 10; // for example: number of rows found

$count = floatval($count);
$rand = rand(1,$count);
```

`$rand` will be number **between 1 and 10**... You need **0..9** for using in MySQL limit. So if **$rand hits 10**, you'll got nothing because your last row is `..LIMIT 9,1`, not `LIMIT 10,1`.

Try this

```
$sql = 'SELECT link, pic, alt FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;';
$res = mysql_query($sql);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
  echo '<a href="/' . $row['link'] . '.php">
          <div class="image">
            <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/' . $row['pic'] . '" alt="' . $row['alt'] . '" />
          </div>
        </a>';
  }
```

Comment: still getting the same result :[

Comment: yes, that was general notice... try this code bellow and let me know what's going on there.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT link, pic, alt FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;
```

Simplified code:

```
<?php

$query = 'SELECT link, pic, alt FROM images ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1;';
// Run the query
if(($result = mysql_query($query)) !== FALSE) {
 list($link, $pic, $alt) = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
          echo '
          <a href="/' . $link . '.php">
            <div class="image">
              <img src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/images/' . $pic . '" 
                   alt="' . $alt . '" 
              />
            </div>
          </a>';
}
?>
```

Comment: Still getting the same result :[